# How to create MediaStream from videofile?

Tags: javascript, video, streaming, webrtc, mediastreamsource

Most of the Mediastream examples are  explanation by webCam-stream.but I need to create MediaStream from local videofile(.webm or mp4).Please tell me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Updated at May 04, 2017**: `captureStream` API are now supported both on Chrome and Firefox.

```
var stream_from_WebM_or_Mp4_File = videoTag.captureStream();
var stream_from_Canvas2D         = canvasTag.captureStream(25);
```

The parameter "25" is requested frame-rates.

Now you can share the resulting stream using either RTCPeerConnection API or record using MediaRecorder API.

Please check a similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42929613/552182

---

There are *two* possibilities:

**1) captureStreamUntilEnded** / [Demo](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/experimental/mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded/)

It is supported only on Firefox as "**`mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded`**".

**2) MediaSource API** [Demo](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pre-recorded-Media-Streaming/)

MediaSource APIs are supported both on chrome and firefox; however, it isn't a realtime media-stream.

What you can do is read file chunks; share them with other users using any transmission gateway like WebSockets, socket.io or WebRTC datachannels; then use MediaSource API to play those chunks as soon as possible instead of waiting from entire file to be shared.

---

Remember, WebRTC implementations both on chromium and gecko supports single but "live" media source in the moment; it means that you **can't use** captured-stream from pre-recorded media **as LIVE media source**. Also, you can't use fake WebAudio stream as LIVE media source.

Following code will NOT work on Firefox:

```
preRecordedMediaStream = preRecordedMedia.mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded();
peer.addStream(preRecordedMediaStream);
```

You can test a demo [here](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/experimental/mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded/).

---

#### Updated at: 1:06 PM - Sunday, July 27, 2014 (UTC)

You can capture pre-recorded mp3/ogg file using FileReader/WebAudio API and share as LIVE audio source to WebRTC peer connections, same as I did in [this demo](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection/stream-mp3-live.html) / [source code](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/blob/36b6cdd842b7995e78c294427d76b78e31480498/RTCMultiConnection/v2.2.2/demos/stream-mp3-live.html).

Comment: Thank you!! Now,I reading your URLpage.I do not finished reading,but It will solve my problem.

Arigato!!

Comment: You say, that mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded does not work in Firefox to stream a pre-recorded file. However you use it in your demo: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/experimental/mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded/ Why? I just tried the demo and obviously it is really not working. Is it just an example made for future Firefox versions?

Comment: I have a question which is the other way around. If I got a MediaStream which created from captureStream() and sourced from a <video> html element. How to output this MediaStream to a local mp4 file?