# audio stream not being added to html canvas

Tags: javascript, audio, canvas, audio-streaming

I have an html canvas that was created in p5, and I would like to add an audio track to it so that I can stream it with a webrtc connection. I currently can stream the visuals but not the audio.

I am adding the audio stream to my canvas as follows:

```
let canvasSource = document.getElementById('canvas-viz');

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true
    }).then(audioStream => {
      audioStream.getAudioTracks().forEach(
        track => { 
          canvasSource.captureStream().addTrack(track) 
        })
      console.log("canv source: ",canvasSource.captureStream().getAudioTracks()); // prints  []
    })
```

So my main problem here is that when I call `canvasSource.captureStream().getAudioTracks()` I get `[]`. So it seems that `addTrack` isn't properly working. I tried calling `canvasSource.captureStream().getAudioTracks()` in the dev tools in case there was some asynchronous tomfoolery happening and also go `[]`. I also tried the following in the dev tools:

```
audioTracks = audioStream.getAudioTracks();
canvasSource.captureStream().addTrack(audioTracks[0]);
```

But this also didn't work, returning `[]` when looking at `getAudioTracks()`. When calling `audioStream.getAudioTracks()`, I get an array of size 1 with my microphone input stream.

I was following methods shown in:
[how to add a audio stream on canvas stream in webrtc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927903/how-to-add-a-audio-stream-on-canvas-stream-in-webrtc)

I am developing this in Chrome. For my purposes, at the time being, it doesn't need to be cross compatible in Firefox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`canvasSource.captureStream()` returns a **new** MediaStream at each call. You have added your audiotrack to a MediaStream you can't access anymore.
Store the canvas MediaStream in a variable accessible there and add the track to that MediaStream.

Answer (score 3):

Kaiido's solution should work.  As an alternative, what I do is simply create a new MediaStream with the tracks from the other two streams...

```
new MediaStream([
  canvasVideoTrack,
  audioTrack
]);
```