# Video playback doesn't reach 60 FPS when using MediaSource

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc, mediastream

I use `video.srcObject = mediaStream; // MediaStream object` to feed a `<video>` tag. (Same as this demo: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/video-video/)

The video is 60 FPS however from `chrome://webrtc-internals` graph, it shows the video FPS sent/receive is constantly at 30FPS. Is this set anywhere that i can change?

FYI - I'm not using `getUserMedia()`, I'm doing exactly the same as the demo -- streaming from a `<video>` to another `<video>` using peer-to-peer connection with WebRTC.

Comment: Can you show your code?  The example you linked to has nothing to do with WebRTC directly (other than that these media components are wrapped up in WebRTC libs), and also does not use MediaSource.  The example uses `captureStream()`, which I've never seen run higher than 30 FPS.

Comment: The code the exactly the same as the WebRTC sample, i forked from it. You're right i'm not using WebRTC directly. So the left video is just using <video> tag to play the a local video which is in 60fps, but according to webrtc-internal stats, the left video is only sending 30fps to the right. That's the part I don't understand.

Comment: In addition to my answer, I might suggest joining video-dev on Slack.  http://video-dev.herokuapp.com/  There are a few folks there who work on the browser implementations of this API.  Perhaps they can provide insight as to why this is locked at 30 FPS max.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to specify the frame rate with `HTML5MediaElement.captureStream()`.

If you were streaming from a Canvas, you *can* specify the frame rate with the first parameter:

```
canvas.captureStream(30);
```

However, I've never seen any capture stream run higher than 30 FPS.  This is a relatively new API, with a lot of implementation quirks and hardcoded items.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'm still very new to video, just started reading about WebRTC since 2 weeks ago. I want to measure the WebRTC decoding performance (like using chrome://webrtc-internal), don't care about P2P connection at all, should I just feed a video stream as MediaStream to <video>? The only way i know is using getUserMedia() but is that fps bounded by the web cam? Sorry for throwing random questions.

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225187/how-to-create-mediastream-from-videofile but it's suggesting using captureStream() which still doesn't go above 30fps.

Comment: I've read a few of your questions... I don't really follow what you're getting at.  `getUserMedia()` is for webcams, capture interfaces, microphones, audio interfaces, etc.  It has nothing to do with regular video *decoding*.  Perhaps you should post a new question that explains the entirety of what you're trying to do from a higher level so we can suggest a better answer.  Alternatively, if you're interested in consulting, please e-mail me at brad@audiopump.co.